# Can RedisTemplate be configured for Redission?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, redisson

I have configured Redisson for Spring Boot. It works fine using RedissonClient. But is it possible to configure Redisson for RedisTemplate. I searched in the web but not found any solution.

```
@Configuration
public class RedissionConfig {

    @Bean
    public Config configRedis() throws IOException {
        return Config.fromYAML(new File("src/main/resources/config/redission-config.yml"));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedissonClient redissonClient() throws IOException {
        return Redisson.create(configRedis());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be used as RedisTemplate. Below is instruction:

https://github.com/redisson/redisson/tree/master/redisson-spring-data